# ETIMEDOUT cannot connect to registry on npx create react app

Tags: create-react-app

Details
I got an error while creating reactjs project, I tried uninstall -g create-react-app and reinstalling but it didn't install

Node.js version
v18.14.2

Example code
npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! syscall connect
npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/create-react-app failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 2606:4700::6810:1a22:443
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly. See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-10-25T04_11_47_030Z-debug-0.log